# Google Maps Markers not showing in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

**Hi, I'm trying to make a website with Google Maps API and get coords from MySQL db**. So far so good, but **only in Chrome or Safari**. **Markers won't show in Internet Explorer**. I could use some help. I followed this guide from Google https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3
Anyway, here's my code. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
var customIcons = {
  sport: {
    icon: 'images/markers/sport.png',
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'images/markers/bar.png',
  },
  poi: {
    icon: 'images/markers/poi.png',
  },
  skola: {
    icon: 'images/markers/skola.png',
  },
  kino: {
    icon: 'images/markers/kino.png',
  },
  divadlo: {
    icon: 'images/markers/divadlo.png',
  }
};

function nactimapu() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.068299, 17.460907),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("querymapa.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var nazev = markers[i].getAttribute("nazev");
      var popis = markers[i].getAttribute("popis");
      var typ = markers[i].getAttribute("typ");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + nazev + "</b> <br/>" + popis;
      var icon = customIcons[typ] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

**Here is xml output in php, maybe there is a mistake. Sorry that I didn't post it earlier.**

```
<?php  

require("dbconfig.php"); 

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbheslo);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM lokace WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'nazev="' . parseToXML($row['nazev']) . '" ';
  echo 'popis="' . parseToXML($row['popis']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'typ="' . $row['typ'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';


// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Comment: Did you figure the issues beetween IE and map marker? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra commas in your arrays:

```
sport: {
     icon: 'images/markers/sport.png',  <-- Right here (among other places)
  }
```

Internet Explorer doesn't like that, while other browsers don't mind them. You can safely remove them.

Answer (score 0):

```
  sport: {icon: 'images/markers/sport.png',},
```

Explorer expects (other browsers ignore this) that you add another command to this, such as latitude - or longitude coordinates and other items specified in your marker. Remove the comma before the closing bracket and you should be fine

as example, i posted below here a marker from my own work, so you can see, when i close the bracket, i dont use a comma anymore

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude),
    map: yay,
    title: title,
    icon: icon
});
```

Comment: Have you tried defining a standard icon to test if its in that code? make a normal reference in your marker statement, letting it create a normal marker from googlemaps standard ... if that shows, you know at least that you ll narrow it down to your costumicon statement), if not, then your problem is deeper. I pulled up my own code from that old project, but i dont see an other error in your code.

Comment: I do get an error on your site in explorer though. Its line 23 in your gmapa.js file. It says the documentElement is empty or is not an object. This might be it, but I cant look into your file like that, unless its the file above, then it is this line where it borks on. `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), {'` bassically it says mapa is not defined then.